# validate one of the Array object in json schema conditionally

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

In below json is valid only if **type** is **mobile** and **endDate** is empty/null, else validation need to fail. Here **type** can have any values but my validation only on *mobile* type.

**Valid json:**

```
{
  "contacts": [
   {
    "type": "mobile",
    "endDate": "",
    "number": "1122334455"
   },
   {
    "type": "home",
    "endDate": "",
    "number": "1111122222"
   },
   {
    "type": "mobile",
    "endDate": "12-Jan-2017",
    "number": "1234567890"
   },
  ]
}
```

**Invalid json:** (since contacts don't have a valid mobile number)

```
{
  "contacts": [
   {
    "type": "mobile",
    "endDate": "12-Jan-2021",
    "number": "1122334455"
   },
   {
    "type": "home",
    "endDate": "",
    "number": "1111122222"
   },
   {
    "type": "mobile",
    "endDate": "12-Jan-2017",
    "number": "1234567890"
   },
  ]
}
```

**Schema which i tried**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "contacts": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "endDate": {
            "type": [
              "string",
              "null"
            ]
          },
          "number": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "if": {
              "properties": {
                "type": {
                  "const": "mobile"
                }
              }
            },
            "then": {
              "properties": {
                "endDate": {
                  "maxLength": 0
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

could anyone provide me a right schema for the above json, attaching the example code [here](https://jsonschema.dev/s/3UMQ4), this is valid json but getting error. Invalid json example is [here](https://jsonschema.dev/s/tkF1j) why because type mobile don't have empty endDate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me the JSON Schema you have so far please? It's difficult for me to suggest a solution when I can't see your schema so far as it may not fit in.

Comment: @Relequestual : i have added what i tried, but not getting what I'm expected.

Comment: Mods: This question should be closed as the problem was a typo and unlikely to help anyone else.
I cannot retract my vote to close and re-cast for a different reason.

Comment: @Relequestual, what you are saying, your comment saying 'running way rather fixing issue'. As we know we should not use exact code what we used,  data privacy constraint. might issue in copy pasted the code.. i edited the above question, if possible kindly provide solutions.

Comment: No, not at all. You should always provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example where possible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - I could not replicate the problem when fixing your copy paste error. Here's a working demo with my suggested "solution" (fixing the typo): https://jsonschema.dev/s/LA432 - If you still have problems, please let me know what they are.

Comment: Where example code had a typo, we are supposed to close the question because it won't help anyone else. There is a specific category for doing so when closing a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer some how, we need not to use `anyOf` or `oneOf`. The right one is **`contains`**. place of the `contains` also a mater. working example is [here](https://jsonschema.dev/s/JbJLE)

**Here is correct schema**

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "contacts": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "contains": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "mobile"
          },
          "endDate": {
            "type" : ["string", "null"],
            "maxLength": 0
          }
        },
        "required": ["type"]
      },
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "endDate": {
            "type": [
              "string",
              "null"
            ]
          },
          "number": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your schema defines `properties > data` but your instance data uses `contacts` rather than `data`. Changing either fixes your problem. You have otherwise done this correctly.

(If you only have one `type` to check, you do not need to wrap your `if/then` schema in an `anyOf`.)

Comment: Question was modified, i used `anyOf`, `oneOf` no luck, kindly provide the solution.

Comment: Please see working example https://jsonschema.dev/s/LA432 - If you have a further problem with a different schema, please create a new question rather than modify this one with a different schema. This solution does what you've asked, as shown in the working example.

Comment: https://jsonschema.dev/s/GGIgL validation successful, 
Expected success for this https://jsonschema.dev/s/3UMQ4 as well

Comment: Why do you expect the second one to be valid? Are your requirements that "at least one of the contacts must be a mobile but without expired" or "if one of the contacts is a mobile, at least one of the mobiles must be without expired"?

Comment: At least one of the mobile contact must be without expired. Is my requirement.

Comment: As you have discovered, `contains` is the solution.